# Highmap for US location based Latitude and Longitude not supporting highmap.js file

Tags: highcharts

We are already using highcharts for web application .Download highmaps and we are implementing highmaps for the same application and our requirement is US map should show based on Latitude and Longitude values . we gone through below link and implemented and its working as expected but got some script error in the browser console its seems highmap.js is conflicting with highchart.js file.

```js
var H = Highcharts,
    map = H.maps['countries/us/us-all'],
    chart;

// Add series with state capital bubbles
$.getJSON('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highcharts/highcharts@v7.0.0/samples/data/us-capitals.json', function (json) {
    var data = [];
    $.each(json, function () {
        this.z = this.population;
        data.push(this);
    });

    chart = Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
        title: {
            text: 'Highmaps lat/lon demo'
        },

        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{point.capital}, {point.parentState}<br>' +
                'Lat: {point.lat}<br>' +
                'Lon: {point.lon}<br>' +
                'Population: {point.population}'
        },

        xAxis: {
            crosshair: {
                zIndex: 5,
                dashStyle: 'dot',
                snap: false,
                color: 'gray'
            }
        },

        yAxis: {
            crosshair: {
                zIndex: 5,
                dashStyle: 'dot',
                snap: false,
                color: 'gray'
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Basemap',
            mapData: map,
            borderColor: '#606060',
            nullColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.2)',
            showInLegend: false
        }, {
            name: 'Separators',
            type: 'mapline',
            data: H.geojson(map, 'mapline'),
            color: '#101010',
            enableMouseTracking: false,
            showInLegend: false
        }, {
            type: 'mapbubble',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.capital}'
            },
            name: 'Cities',
            data: data,
            maxSize: '12%',
            color: H.getOptions().colors[0]
        }]
    });
});

// Display custom label with lat/lon next to crosshairs
$('#container').mousemove(function (e) {
    var position;
    if (chart) {
        if (!chart.lab) {
            chart.lab = chart.renderer.text('', 0, 0)
                .attr({
                    zIndex: 5
                })
                .css({
                    color: '#505050'
                })
                .add();
        }

        e = chart.pointer.normalize(e);
        position = chart.fromPointToLatLon({
            x: chart.xAxis[0].toValue(e.chartX),
            y: chart.yAxis[0].toValue(e.chartY)
        });

        chart.lab.attr({
            x: e.chartX + 5,
            y: e.chartY - 22,
            text: 'Lat: ' + position.lat.toFixed(2) + '<br>Lon: ' + position.lon.toFixed(2)
        });
    }
});

$('#container').mouseout(function () {
    if (chart && chart.lab) {
        chart.lab.destroy();
        chart.lab = null;
    }
});
```

```css
#container {
    height: 500px;
    min-width: 310px;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.loading {
    margin-top: 10em;
    text-align: center;
    color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.3.6/proj4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/highmaps.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/offline-exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/us/us-all.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Here is jsfiddler for this issue.

```js
var H = Highcharts,
    map = H.maps['countries/us/us-all'],
    chart;

// Add series with state capital bubbles
$.getJSON('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highcharts/highcharts@v7.0.0/samples/data/us-capitals.json', function (json) {
    var data = [];
    $.each(json, function () {
        this.z = this.population;
        data.push(this);
    });

    chart = Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
        title: {
            text: 'Highmaps lat/lon demo'
        },

        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{point.capital}, {point.parentState}<br>' +
                'Lat: {point.lat}<br>' +
                'Lon: {point.lon}<br>' +
                'Population: {point.population}'
        },

        xAxis: {
            crosshair: {
                zIndex: 5,
                dashStyle: 'dot',
                snap: false,
                color: 'gray'
            }
        },

        yAxis: {
            crosshair: {
                zIndex: 5,
                dashStyle: 'dot',
                snap: false,
                color: 'gray'
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Basemap',
            mapData: map,
            borderColor: '#606060',
            nullColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.2)',
            showInLegend: false
        }, {
            name: 'Separators',
            type: 'mapline',
            data: H.geojson(map, 'mapline'),
            color: '#101010',
            enableMouseTracking: false,
            showInLegend: false
        }, {
            type: 'mapbubble',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.capital}'
            },
            name: 'Cities',
            data: data,
            maxSize: '12%',
            color: H.getOptions().colors[0]
        }]
    });
});

// Display custom label with lat/lon next to crosshairs
$('#container').mousemove(function (e) {
    var position;
    if (chart) {
        if (!chart.lab) {
            chart.lab = chart.renderer.text('', 0, 0)
                .attr({
                    zIndex: 5
                })
                .css({
                    color: '#505050'
                })
                .add();
        }

        e = chart.pointer.normalize(e);
        position = chart.fromPointToLatLon({
            x: chart.xAxis[0].toValue(e.chartX),
            y: chart.yAxis[0].toValue(e.chartY)
        });

        chart.lab.attr({
            x: e.chartX + 5,
            y: e.chartY - 22,
            text: 'Lat: ' + position.lat.toFixed(2) + '<br>Lon: ' + position.lon.toFixed(2)
        });
    }
});

$('#container').mouseout(function () {
    if (chart && chart.lab) {
        chart.lab.destroy();
        chart.lab = null;
    }
});
```

```css
#container {
    height: 500px;
    min-width: 310px;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.loading {
    margin-top: 10em;
    text-align: center;
    color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.3.6/proj4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/highmaps.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/offline-exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/us/us-all.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

if you remove highchart.js script reference it will work and it will show the map but highchart.js required for us for bar chart and etc. for existing functional for chat will not work for us.

we are using below js files. proj4.js highmaps.js us-all.js

I downloaded highmaps files and added highmaps.js , proj4.js and us-all.js to my project and got above issues.

The highchart and highmap should work in same web application. js files should not conflict and should not show any script error in console.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading Highcharts and Highmaps like this ([JSFiddle of problem](https://jsfiddle.net/2v73pfmt/)):

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/highmaps.js"></script>
```

Load Highcharts and then the map module ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2v73pfmt/1/)):

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/map.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Halvor for your response but not working for me. map.src.js:31 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parts/Globals.js' of undefined  us-all.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'countries/us/us-all' of undefined
    at us-all.js:1

Comment: @manimaran I'll check it out, but your error changed, correct? No longer the conflict but instead the message you commented?

Comment: this error  Uncaught Error: Highcharts error #16: www.highcharts.com/errors/16  is gone but got error which i commented last time

Comment: @ManiMaran I think your new error might be caused by version mismatching. Could you confirm that your `highcharts.js` and `map.js` are of the same Highcharts version number?

Comment: Additionally, could you please show us the order of loading your scripts?